# What would the launch and explosion of FTL-missiles look like?

Tags: science-fiction, faster-than-light

In [Effects of being hit by an object going at FTL speeds](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/191932/effects-of-being-hit-by-an-object-going-at-ftl-speeds), the effects of a spear going at FTL speeds are debated in detail.

For my setting, humanity's last hope of stalling an alien invasion comes from the creation of an FTL-capable missile launched to destroy the main alien fleet. It is based on the [Alcubierre Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) (I use that because there is plenty of resources on that topic), the same type of warp drive used in the aforementioned post.

What would it look like? (since the setting I am currently developing will be mostly used in visual material)

Effects mentioned in the post include "a burst of Gravitational Cherenkov Radiation", creation of extremely hot plasma if used in an atmosphere etc.

*Note: I use the `science-based` because I want something plausible to build the style of my universe.*

---

**EDIT: after reading the comment, it might be better to say that the fleet orbits a planet and that the missile is going to it the planet. I forgot to add the mass of the missile, probably several tons.**

Comment: I wonder what will happen when that alien fleet would enter warped space segment of the missile's Alcubierre drive, and should they use the same, what would happen to the missile. Warp aside, this is no FTL, and normal physics laws apply. I expect disintegration of target if objects actually collide and about nothing if the missile would miss, probably some warp metrics fluctuation could cause some minor damage on the alien ship(s) when missile would pass by, but nothing too heavy.

Comment: Commenting as I'm only guessing... but the actual 'explosion' would probably only behave like an extremely penetrative kinetic impact and would probably only affect a single object(kinetic impact forces imparted does not translate well over the vacuum of space between ships). As for the launch, a 'gravitational' 'burst' makes me think there's going to be inward optical(light) distortion similar to what a black hole does.

Comment: @vesper No FTL collision but I imagine the heat, radiation, and junk from around the bubble would do something

Comment: Unlikely the debris would do damage t9 the rest of the fleet, at least whatever plasma would appear wouldn't be any more damaging than neutral gas in space to a ship going at subluminal speed. Mayhe some radiation spike would occur, but the plasma cloud from the collision will very soon be left behind the advancing aliens, and anyway it takes time for the cloud to spread, which will not be enough to damage even adjacent ships (space-wise).

Comment: So, if the fleet is orbiting a planet, and the missile hit the planet, what would happen then? The debris of the planet would damage the fleet for sure. Indeed, if the missile hits nothing, there won't be much happening.

Comment: Hmm, planet. Let's say the missile impacts at 0.5c, and has relativistic mass of 1e4 kg (10 ton). The impact will have an energy of 1e4*1.5e8^2/2=1.125e20 J, way not enough to break the planet into pieces. Probably the impact will still blow a chunk of matter off the back of the planet, that will hit whatever was unlucky with some 1e8-1e10 J, potentially rendering a ship out of order. The planet will suffer harder, tectonic shockwaves can well turn its crust into molten lava, leaving the fleet without support. So aliens will go one way to wipe humans for this atrocity. Everyone dies, XKCDstyle

Comment: science-based, faster-than-light: choose one.

Comment: As is pointed out in that question, the answer w/r to an FTL projectile is either "we don't know", or "everything everywhere dies".  Under general relativity, nothing can travel FTL, so infinite energy would be required to reach lightspeed, and infinite energy is an infinite explosion.  The plasma is for a relativistic projectile, the Cherenkov radiation is speculative and only occurs as a "sonic boom" effect near the speed of light, not characteristic of an Albucierre  drive.

Comment: The effect of an impactor is dependent almost entirely on the energy required to put it into motion.  An Alcubierre drive is speculated to only require [about 700kg of mass-energy](https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/164326-nasa-discusses-its-warp-drive-research-prepares-to-create-a-warp-bubble-in-the-lab), so an impactor that was thus equipped would hit with, at most, the energy equivalent of a 350kg antimatter bomb.  Definitely big, but if you can build an Alcubierre drive, you have much better weapon options.

Comment: Mathematically, above the speed of light, the energy of your projectile becomes *imaginary,* which we don't even really know what that means in physical terms. It could be nothing happens because the energy is directed out of our universe. You're asking for a lot of speculation here.

Comment: @void_ptr The science-based tag is a lot more forgiving than the hard-science tag.

Comment: @Jdunlop General relativity says nothing with mass can travel *AT* the speed of light. It does not say nothing can travel *faster* than light. The problem is that with a velocity faster than light, your mass, energy, and or time (take your pick) becomes imaginary, and we don't know what that means. It is perfectly consistent for mass-ful particles to travel faster than light, so long as they *always* travel faster than light. A particle traveling faster than c cannot slow to below c in the same way that a particle below c cannot speed to above c.

Comment: @stix - sorry, I should've been more precise.  What I meant by my comment was "nothing can accelerate to FTL", but that wasn't what I wrote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138618/discussion-between-jdunlop-and-stix).

Comment: I think even the [tag:science-based] tag is inappropriate. We have some fun science discussions about FTLish things like the Alcubierre drive, but that's just mathematical speculation at this point. So I believe you should swap the [tag:science-based] tag for [tag:science-fiction], since that's the best you can possibly get out of any answer. Thank you, however, for specifically identifying the nature of your FTL. I wouldn't upvote any answer that didn't take the effect of A.D.'s contracted space into account. That might be more devastating than the actual kinetic impact.

Comment: @JBH i changed the tag to `science-fiction`.  I thought the `science_based` tag was more appropriate since I asked for realistic but not perfectly scientifically accurate answers. The effects of such weapon are difficult to imagine and might be not as "cool" as I thought, I assume I might just choose something simpler, but more effective.

Answer (score 3):

## Energy In = Energy Out

At relativistic speeds, any explosive warhead in a missile is pretty irrelevant, so we can treat it as a dumb impactor.

*Gravitational Cherenkov Radiation*

You mention this as being a symptom listed in the other question, but you need to read more closely:

> What is dangerous though is the burst of Gravitational Cherenkov Radiation. This circular blast wave (perpendicular to the velocity of the spear) **centred on the point at which the spear crossed the lightspeed barrier will carry almost all of the energy that went into accelerating the spear**. Depending on how much of the crossover the handwavium applies to, this could be an astronomical amount

The two important points - the effect would be centred around the point at which the missile passes lightspeed, and it is wholly dependent on the energy used in accelerating it.  (And it does not use an Alcubierre drive, but rather handwaves passing the infinite energy barrier of reaching lightspeed.)

*Extremely Hot Plasma*

This is mentioned in the other question in reference to the [*What If* Relativistic Baseball](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/).  Notably, in the original article:

> We'll suppose it's a normal pitch, except in the instant the pitcher releases the ball, it magically accelerates to 0.9c.

All the subsequent effects are a function of the energy required to accelerate the baseball, which is applied magically.  Your postulated missile is being launched by energy provided by the human fleet.

So an FTL missile, as an impactor, will do damage proportionate to the energy used to accelerate it.  Exotic matter of the sort required for an Alcubierre drive would react poorly with normal matter, so it would probably approximate an antimatter/matter explosion.  With a 1 tonne payload, that would be somewhere in the vicinity of a two gigatonne explosion.  Not small, but not special.

Any fleet that could *launch* such a missile can do better damage by other means.

(For reference, the [Chicxulub Impact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicxulub_crater) was about a hundred thousand gigatonnes.)